# Check that PDF has been created before displaying?

Tags: php, laravel, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I am creating a PDF, from a template, using JasperPHP.

I then immediately try to display it.

How can I ensure that it is completely created, before displaying?

I am checking that the file exists but the PDF is corrupt, at this point, so I am assuming it is still being created.

I have also tried using flock, to open it with an exclusive lock, but this seems to work, even when the PDF is not completely rendered.

This is what I am doing (the dd is just for testing, it never gets here):

```
/**
     * Check that we can lock a file
     * this ensures that it has been completely created.
     *
     * @param $filename
     * @return bool
     */
    function stillWriting($filename)
    {
        $stillWriting = true;

        if($fp = fopen($filename, "r+"))
        {
            if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) // Try to get an exclusive lock on the file
            {
                flock($fp, LOCK_UN); // Unlock - we're just checking
                $stillWriting = false;
            }else{
                dd('failed');
            }
            fclose($fp);
        }
        return $stillWriting;
    }
```

Mick

**Edit - added more detail**

This is where the PDF gets created:

```
exec($this->the_command, $output, $return_var);
```

I am using https://github.com/cossou/JasperPHP

It executes JasperStart [https://sourceforge.net/projects/

This is where the PDF is displayed:

`return Response::make(file_get_contents($this->outputFilename .'.pdf'), 200, [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
            'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="' . $this->outputFilename .'.pdf' .'"'
        ]);`

**The actual problem that I am getting is that Chrome says "Failed to load PDF document", I am guessing from this, that it is a timing problem. The file opens correctly If I then go to Windows and double click.**

Comment: How does the PDF get displayed? Rendered in the browser? Printed and delivered by carrier pigeon? Loaded over a network drive using Windows Explorer via double-click into a PDF reader? Is the PDF available for download via the browser for a period of 24 hours after the request is made? Is the PDF regenerated or cached per request? Please update your question with more details.

Comment: The reason for the questions is that if the PDF is being loaded into a web 
browser immediately after being generated by JasperReports, there's no need to first save it to a local file. Stream it directly to the browser (and write unit tests to find all the conditions whereupon the report could be empty, then fix those tests).

Comment: This is confusing, are you creating the pdf asynchronously? How could this happen? Why not check the data before creating the pdf to determine if its empty? The pdf MUST be written to a local file ( or remote) file.

Answer (score 0):

JasperPHP has a flag `$background = true`.

If I set this to false it looks like it waits for the compile to finish before continuing.

Mick